# Integrating OpenAM, tomcat J2EE policy agent with Spring Security-enabled web application

Tags: grails, spring-security, openam

We are trying to do fine-grained authorizations using spring security while having user  authentication and coarse-grained authorization using openam policies feature for the application realm. What I mean by coarse-grained is simple URI rules with subjects. What I mean by fine-grained authorization is at web application level such as using **ACLs using spring-security-acls**.

To accomplish this, an approach that I have thought is to use ** Spring Security PreAuthenticationFilters** as outlined in spring-security reference manual. I got this thought after reading this question [pre-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708393/grails-spring-security-abstractpreauthenticatedprocessingfilter-redirect/pre-authentication%20filter)

To do rapid prototyping, I have chosen Grails 2.2.3 as the web application platform with plugins for spring-security-core and acls behind OpenAM and openam J2EE policy agent interfaces. The OpenAM policy is setup to authenticate a user and return the uid (Ldap user id) in the policy response header. This is mapped to USER_ID in the response provider and sent as HTTP header by the policy agent.

The grails application **resources.groovy** looks like this:

```
beans = {
   preAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService(PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService)



preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider) {
    preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService =   ref('preAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService')
 }

requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter) {
    authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
    principalRequestHeader = 'USER_ID'
 }
}
```

The **BootStrap.groovy** looks like this:

```
def init = {
    servletContext -> 
    
    SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter',SecurityFilterPosition.PRE_AUTH_FILTER);
}
```

When I tested this in my local setup, I get errors ...

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException: USER_ID header not found in request.
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
```

Any clues on how to solve the issue, or comments/suggestions on the approach itself?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Agent filter must be the  first one in the filter chain ... assured?

If yes, you have to set debug level to 'message' in the agent profile and inspect the debug log, most likely your agent config is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks. I fixed the header variable. The problem is in mapping the authentication token to granted authorities. Trying to understand the flow from Spring Security manual.

Comment: @user2527121 : Hey, I am trying to achieve the same thing, can you walk me through the steps please. I need the spring security config part.